# Get username from local session Telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm using [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library to crawl some telegram channels. While crawling, i need to resolve many join links, usernames and channel ids. To resolve these items, i used method `client.get_entity()` but after a while telegram servers banned my crawler for resolving too many usernames. I searched around and found from this [issue](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/494), i should use `get_input_entity()` instead of `get_entity()`. Actually telethon saves entities inside a local SQLite file and whenever a call to `get_input_entity()` is made, it first searches the local SQLite database, if no match found it then sends request to telegram servers. So far so good but i have two problems with this approach:

1. `get_input_entity()` just returns two attributes: *ID* and *hash* but there are other columns like *username*, *phone* and *name* in the SQLite database. I need a method to not just return *ID* and *hash*, but to return other columns too.
2. I need to control the number of resolve requests sent to telegram server but `get_input_entity()` sends request to telegram servers whenever founds no match in the local database. The problem is that i can't control this method when to request telegram servers. Actually i need a boolean argument for this method indicating whether or not the method should send a request to telegram servers when no match in the local database is found.

I read some of the telethon source codes, mainly `get_input_entity()` and wrote my own version of `get_input_entity()`:

```
def my_own_get_input_entity(self, target, with_info: bool = False):
    if self._client:
        if target in ('me', 'self'):
            return types.InputPeerSelf()
        def get_info():
            nonlocal self, result
            res_id = 0
            if isinstance(result, InputPeerChannel):
                res_id = result.channel_id
            elif isinstance(result, InputPeerChat):
                res_id = result.chat_id
            elif isinstance(result, InputPeerUser):
                res_id = result.user_id
            return self._sqlite_session._execute(
                'select username, name from entities where id = ?', res_id
            )
        try:
            result = self._client.session.get_input_entity(target)
            info = get_info() if with_info else None
            return result, info
        except ValueError:
            record_current_time()

        try:
            # when we are here, we are actually going to
            # send request to telegram servers
            if not check_if_appropriate_time_elapsed_from_last_telegram_request():
                return None
            result = self._client.get_input_entity(target)
            info = get_info() if with_info else None
            return result, info
        except ChannelPrivateError:
            pass
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except Exception:
            pass
```

But my code is somehow performance problematic because it makes redundant queries to SQLite database. For example, if the `target` is actually an entity inside the local database and `with_info` is `True`, it first queries the local database in line `self._client.session.get_input_entity(target)` and checks if `with_info` is `True`, then queries the database again to get *username* and *name* columns. In another situation, if `target` is not found inside the local database, calling `self._client.get_input_entity(target)` makes a redundant call to local database.

Knowing these performance issues, i delved deeper in telethon source codes but as i don't know much about *asyncio*, i couldn't write any better code than above.

Any ideas how to solve the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.session.get_input_entity` will make no API call (it can't), and fails if there is no match in the local database, which is probably the behaviour you want.

You can, for now, access the `client.session._conn` private attribute. It's a `sqlite3.Connection` object so you can use that to make all the queries you want. Note that this is prone to breaking since you're accessing a private member although no changes are expected soon. Ideally, you should subclass the session file to suit your needs. See [Session Files](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/advanced-usage/sessions.html) in the documentation.